# MissingReferenceException at scene unload time

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, scene

I want to store my data when current running scene was unloaded. For this purpose I have written following code:

```
void OnDisable ()
 {
     BackUpPuzzleData();
 }

 public void BackUpPuzzleData ()
 {
     if (DataStorage.RetrievePuzzleStatus (difficultyLevel, puzzleId) == Constants.PUZZLE_NOT_OPENED
         && DataStorage.RetrievePuzzleStatus (difficultyLevel, puzzleId) != Constants.PUZZLE_COMPLETED)
         DataStorage.StorePuzzleStatus (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, Constants.PUZZLE_RUNNING);

     if (DataStorage.RetrievePuzzleStatus (difficultyLevel, puzzleId) == Constants.PUZZLE_RUNNING)
         StorePuzzleData ();
 }


 private void StorePuzzleData ()
 {
     DataStorage.StorePuzzleTimePassed (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, GameController.gamePlayTime);

     foreach (Transform cell in gridTransform) {
         CellInformation cellInfo = cell.GetComponent<CellInformation> ();
         if (cellInfo != null) {
             CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellNumber (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.number);
             CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellColor (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.CellColor);
             CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellDisplayColor (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.CellDisplayColor);
         }
     }
 }
```

But when OnDisable method gets called at that time Console giving me following error:

[image]

I have already set execution order of scrip in project settings then why I am getting this kind of error?

**GOAL:** Basically I want to save current game play data so when game player return back he can again start from which he left game.

Comment: Why exactly this sequence? Can you try save data at first and unload scene after saving finished?

Comment: Is there an event that you can process before OnDisable? It would seem that you've lost access to the objects that you need to interrogate by that stage.

Comment: How would you decide anevent when the scene is about to unload ? e.g., some back button click ?

Comment: I can't use back buttons or on screen main menu button for this purpose. Because I am working on iPhone too. So if game play directly press there home button and exit from game then there is no way exist to backup their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing some time with this problem, now I can able to figure out this problem. I don't know how much solution was correct but at least now working for me.

Here I am discussing this because some members get some hint from this.

At game load time, I filled up one list with all cell's script. Each cell of grid has one script attached **CellInformation**. So I prepare list of all these cells script.

At game disable time, I fetched value from these scripts and store into local storage. I can able to access scripts but not game objects from list because they were already destroyed.

```
void OnDisable ()
{
    StorePuzzleData ();
}

private void StorePuzzleData ()
{
    DataStorage.StorePuzzleTimePassed (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, GameController.gamePlayTime);

    foreach (CellInformation cellInfo in cellInfoList) {
        CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellNumber (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.number);
        CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellColor (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.CellColor);
        CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellDisplayColor (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.CellDisplayColor);
        CellStorage.StorePuzzleCellGroupComplete (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, cellInfo.RowIndex, cellInfo.ColIndex, cellInfo.IsGroupComplete ? 1 : 0);
    }

}
```

I hope this will give some hints to other programmers.

Comment: Im sorry... I dont mean to be rude... but, how old are you? It´s so naive to believe the game will never crash :D

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion, instead of saving when scene unload you could save everytime the player makes a move, this way even if the game crashes you can recover from the last time the player made a move.

This scene unloading, will occur automatically or will the user make any action (like clicking a button)? If it is a player event, you should put your save code on that button, because, as far as I could research, the OnDisable behaviour will be called after your objects gets destroyed, making it impossible for you to store their data.

Comment: Basically I am working on Sudoku game so storing data per game player movement seem not to be correct as per my thinking.

Comment: Many games, far more complex than sudoku, does it like that. Fallout Shelter for instance, if you simply exit the game pressing home button it will resume right where you were.

Comment: I suggested that you keep writing to disk every move, because doing this will gurantee that, if your player quits or the phone freezes, you will always have his last play saved. It may sound hard, but its easier than you think, you can save how your board is setup and then you keep saving how the player did the play, then you read it from top to bottom and you have the last play.

Comment: I clearly understand your point and up vote as well for this reply :)